# MS Access query check if form field is empty

Tags: ms-access

I have a multi-field form and use it to retrieve records of a table. If there is no user input in a field I want to allow "*" and Null Values for the according column, the user input otherwise.

I tried

```
Like IIf([Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel]="" Or IsNull([Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel]);Like "*" Or Is Null;[Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel])
```

as well as

```
Like IIf(IsEmpty([Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel]);Like "*" Or Is Null;[Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel])
```

But in both cases, the IIf function always triggers the else expression.
How can I check whether the field in the form is empty? Is this even possible without VB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, when `[Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel]` contains a value, you want only those rows where some field contains that value.

But, if `[Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel]` is Null or an empty string, you want to retrieve all the rows.

If that is correct, try a `WHERE` clause similar to this:

```
WHERE
       Len([Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel] & '') = 0
    OR some_field Like '*' & [Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel] & '*'
```

Also add a `PARAMETERS` clause at the beginning of your SQL statement:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frm_searchForm]![Titel] Text ( 255 );
```