# MS Access multi field search with empty fields or multiple selections from list boxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

can some one kindly help me with MS Access? My problem is similar to the one in the following link:

[MS Access multi field search with empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863819/ms-access-multi-field-search-with-empty-fields)

but in my case, each search field is a list box from which we can select multiple things.

In my case, the user of the database application will enter start date and end date (text boxes) which will populate the list boxes (cost center, item number, employee id) from a single database table matching the rows that have effective date falling between start date and end date. After populating the list boxes, the user has the choice to either select multiple cost centers or leave the search field blank, multiple item numbers or blank,  multiple employee numbers or blank. After selecting, if the command button display results is pressed, we should be able to get the results which satisfy all these search criteria. For example, if I select cost centers 1301, 1302 and employee no.s 492128, 492690, 492959 and leave the item numbers search field blank, then in the data table, all the entries that match these cost centers and employee no.s (all the search fields are separate columns) which fall between the start date and end date should be displayed.

I am unable to get the logic in VB. Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build up an sql statement in vba then run it using a recordset, to get the results back.

Obviously I dont know what the data you'll need to get is, or from the tables you;ll get it from, however the where clause needs to be built as follows:

```
dim wc as string
wc = wc & iif(lst_costcenter.ItemsSelected.Count = 0, "", " AND " & InClause(lst_costcenter, "tablename.columnname", false))
wc = wc & iif(lst_itemnumber.ItemsSelected.Count = 0, "", " AND " & InClause( ...
```

Finally when building the sql statement, you'll need to chop of the first "AND" in wc & replace it with "WHERE"

```
wc = iif(wc <> "", " WHERE " & mid(trim(wc), 5), "")
```

InClause is a function that you need to add in a module, or in the enquiry form itself:
It uses 3 arguments:
1. The listbox control to build an in clause for,
2. A string comprising tablename-dot-columnname being the table/column to be filtered for the values selected in the listbox, &
3. True/False according to whether the datatype of the column is string (true) or numeric (false)

```
Public Function InClause(lst as ListBox, tblcol as string, isAlpha as boolean)
    Dim si As String
    Dim vv As Variant

    For Each vv In lstBox.ItemsSelected
        If isAlpha Then
            si = si & "," & Chr(34) & lstBox.Column(0, vv) & Chr(34)
        Else
            si = si & "," & lstBox.Column(0, vv)
        End If
    Next vv

    If si <> "" Then
        si = "(" & tblcol & " IN (" & mid(si, 2) & "))"
    End If
    InClause = si
End Function
```

Hope this helps